# determine which column is most similar

Tags: variance, inference, descriptive-statistics

I have a dataset with individuals and their scores in 15 categories. I would like to find which category is the least different among itself, or rather most similar among those individuals. 
Can i compare variances between those categories (as long as n stays the same) to say that a group with a smaller variance is necessarily more similar than a group with higher variance?

Answer (score 1):

that's the purpose of variance, yes.

you can also use analogous statistics like range, interquantile range or mean absolute deviation. whatever you think it serves better your goal.